# How to query multiple children in Firebase with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an Android app that asks the user for a or multiple languages and saves them in a list, and then returns contents(using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) depending on the language(s) i.e how can I retrieve the children of Arabic and English(03,01)for example?. All I could get are the children of data using:

```
mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("data");
```

My Database:

```
"data" : {
    "Arabic" : {
      "01" : {}
    },
    "English" : {
      "03" : {}
    },
    "French" : {
      "02" : {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed database and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Alex I updated the post with the database.

Comment: And what is the exact data you want to get?

Comment: He needs to fetch data from multiple childs

Comment: I want to get children of languages that are in a list for example if I have a list L=[Arabic,French] I want to fetch children of Arabic and French before sending the data to firebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be struggling with how to traverse the `DataSnapshot` that you get back when reading from Firebase.

To navigate the data in your question, you'd do something like:

```
mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("data");
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot languageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(languageSnapshot.getKey()); // "Arabic", "English", "French"
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: languageSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey()); // "01", "03", "02"
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [reading a list of data with a value event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: Thank you Frank, is it possible to display the childSnapshots in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: Sure, but also building a custom adapter for you is a bit beyond what we can reasonably do in a Stack Overflow question. I recommend reading https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview to learn how to apply the code in my answer to a custom adapter.